# Asp.NET webservice com página em branco no IIS 8

Tags: asp.net, web-service, iis, asmx

Tenho um webservice (asmx) hospedado na Kinghost.

Após feita uma atualização no IIS (da versão 6 para 8) o webservice deixou de funcionar. Ao tentar acessar o webservice pelo navegador mostra uma página em branco, não mostra os métodos:

http://www.fsoft.com.br/ibpt/service.asmx

Uitlizo Asp.NET 3.5.

É preciso fazer algum tipo de configuração extra no web.config ou na aplicação?

Comment: Ao menos p/ mim está funcionando corretamente.

Answer (score 1):

Pode ser necessário desabilitar as páginas de erros customizadas para ver o erro. 
Fiz este post que pode ajudar:
http://aplicacoesweb.blogspot.com.br/2013/11/iis7-abre-pagina-aspnet-em-branco.html